# jRuby hash iteration newbie here

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, jruby

I am very new to rails in general and what I have is a hash being passed as json for one format and now I need to pass it to the view to work with but I have no idea how to iterate over the hash to make it work in the view as I need to do some type of each loop over it. Its a 2 dimensional hash dunno if that means anything or not.

**edit**

example

```
{"status":"successful","service_list":[{"service_name":"mySQL","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"No errors reported","host":"1"},{"service_name":"PHP","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"No errors reported","host":"1"},{"service_name":"APache","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"No errors reported","host":"1"},{"service_name":"Jetty","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"No errors reported","host":"1"}]}
```

This renders fine when I do it as JSON, but using the same thing to render it out in an HTML based view is where I am getting stuck

Comment: can you please post the example data and how you want to loop through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have converted a Ruby has to a JSON hash, which is a Javascript format. In Ruby you would access a hash as follows:

```
hash = {"foo": "bar"}
puts hash["foo"] # This returns "bar"
```

JSON is similar to Ruby, and can be accessed in the same manner:

```
var hash = {"foo": "bar"};
alert(hash["foo"]); # This alerts "bar"
```

If you want to iterate through this collection in Javascript, you can use a for loop:

```
var data = {"status":"successful","service_list":[{"service_name":"mySQL","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"No errors reported","host":"1"},{"service_name":"PHP","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"No errors reported","host":"1"},{"service_name":"APache","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"No errors reported","host":"1"},{"service_name":"Jetty","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"No errors reported","host":"1"}]};
for(x=0;x<data["service_list"].length;x++) {
  alert(data["service_list"][x]["service_name"]); # This returns "mySQL", ...
};
```

If you are wanting to convert this JSON object to a Ruby has you can call "JSON.parse" with your JSON string as an argument.